# How can I change a brand image on scroll in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have managed to make the image change when I scroll it but it positioning is all wrong and out of the nav bar. I'd like the image to change color when the user scrolls down, but putting the image in the CSS like this positions it wrong. Is there a good way to do it?

CSS:

```
      #fh5co-header .navbar-brand {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: 700;
      padding-left: 0;
      color: #fff;
      background: url(../images/loc2.png);


    }
    #fh5co-header.navbar-fixed-top {
      position: fixed !important;
      background: #fff;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 9px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 9px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 9px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      box-shadow: 0 0 9px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      margin-top: 0px;
      top: 0;

#fh5co-header.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-brand {
  background: url(../images/loc.png);
  color: #96281B;
```

HTML:

```
    #fh5co-header.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-brand {
      background: url(../images/loc.png);
      color: #96281B;


            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <!-- Mobile Toggle Menu Button -->
                        <a href="#" class="js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"><i></i></a>
                     <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"></a> 
                    </div>
                    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#" data-nav-section="home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="work"><span>Menus</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="testimonials"><span>Testimonials</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="services"><span>Services</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="about"><span>About</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="contact"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-facebook"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a></li>


                      </ul>
                        <ul class="social social-circle">

                            </ul>
                    </div>
                    </nav>
```

JS

```
var windowScroll = function() {
    var lastScrollTop = 0;

    $(window).scroll(function(event){

        var header = $('#fh5co-header'),
            scrlTop = $(this).scrollTop();

        if ( scrlTop > 500 && scrlTop <= 2000 ) {


            header.addClass('navbar-fixed-top fh5co-animated slideInDown');
        } else if ( scrlTop <= 500) {
            if ( header.hasClass('navbar-fixed-top') ) {
                header.addClass('navbar-fixed-top fh5co-animated slideOutUp');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    header.removeClass('navbar-fixed-top fh5co-animated slideInDown slideOutUp');
                }, 100 );
            }
        } 

    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like this.

Create classes to switch between, where you can set a background-image.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 80) {
        $(".navy").addClass("scrolling");
        $(".navbar-brand").addClass("navscroll");
    } else {
        $(".navy").removeClass("scrolling");
        $(".navbar-brand").removeClass("navscroll");
    }
    });
```

CSS:

```css
.drop.menuscroll {
  margin-top: 0px;
  transition: 0.8s
}
.menu.linesscroll {
  margin-top: 8px;
  transition: 0.8s;
}
.navy.scrolling {
  transition: 0.8s;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.navbar-brand img.navscroll {
  margin-top: -10px;
  width: 63px;
  transition: 0.8s;
}
```

Place tha class on the navbar etc. This worked for me. 
All you need to do is amend the class specifics to fit your project.